# MVC 4 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best practice for adding javascript to a page? Should I create a folder and add a .js file for each page? Then, I can add a reference to the javascript file at the bottom my view page.  should I embed the javascript code at the bottom of the page instead of create the .js file? Does it make a difference?

Comment: IMHO, it's whatever works for you and is easy to understand/maintain. You could simply include them in the view, make it modular (and possibly use requireJS/YepNope), or try to make it out of one file you can compress/minify. AngularJS (to my knowledge) takes the approach you're talking about (for good, bad or indifferent).

Comment: As there can be many answers to this, how about changing to "*What are the relevant considerations*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RequireJS for .NET. There is a NuGet package out for that.

Great info about setting up and handleing requireJs out here : http://requirejsnet.veritech.io/ .

Your JS modules will look something like

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap'
], function ($) {

    var indexScript = function () {
        this.init();
    };

    indexScript.prototype.init = function () {
        //do stuff with bootstrap
    };

    //create object on DOM ready
    $(function () {
        var entryPoint = new indexScript();
    });
});
```

You can configure your dependencies like in a config json file like this :

```
{
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2",
        "jquery-validate": "jquery.validate",
        "jquery-validate-unobtrusive": "jquery.validate.unobtrusive",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap",
        "respond": "respond",
        "i18n": "Components/RequireJS/i18n",
        "text": "Components/RequireJS/text",
        "menu-module" : "Controllers/Common/menu-module"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery-validate": {
            "deps": [ "jquery" ]
        },
        "jquery-validate-unobtrusive": {
            "deps": [ "jquery", "jquery-validate" ]
        },
        "bootstrap": { 
            "deps":  ["jquery"]
        }
    },
    "autoBundles": {
        "main-app": {
            "outputPath": "Scripts/Bundles/",
            "include": [
                {
                    "directory": "Controllers/Root"
                }
            ]
        },
        "require-plugins": {
            "outputPath": "Scripts/Bundles/",
            "include": [
                {
                    "file": "Components/RequireJS/i18n"
                },
                {
                    "file": "Components/RequireJS/text"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

in a RequireJS approach.

LATER EDIT : @Anders RequireJS for .NET supports bundling and minification using a YUI compressor defined here : http://requirejsnet.veritech.io/compressor.html and versioned caching. ( sorry that i could not comment.

Answer (score 1):

Always make separate .js files for javascript and do not embed the javascript directly in the view. This is much better for maintanence. But, beware, it's for network performance reasons always better to have less count on files which the client has to download (think of mobile users!). So i suggest you to use minification and bundleing which ASP.NET offers!

Answer (score 1):

It is bad to embed large chunks of JS into HTML because .js, .css and image files don't change often and browsers can cache those. But HTML is usually generated automatically and can't be cached therefor.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid embeded javascript.  I recommend using [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), but you can still have different javascript files, like utilities.js , dialogs.js etc.